# Function returning "This" object in C++

Tags: c++, return, this, this-pointer

So, following is a member function of Class Sales_data which is defined outside the class,

```
Sales_data& Sales_data::combine(const Sales_data &rhs) {
    units_sold += rhs.units_sold;
    revenue += rhs.revenue; //adding the members of rhs into the members of "this" object
    return *this;
} //units_sold and revenue are both data members of class
```

When the function is called, it is called like

```
total.combine(trans); //total and trans are the objects of class
```

What i am not understanding is the function returning `*this`,
i understand it returns an instance of the object but it is not returning that instance to anything as we can see during function call, also if i don't write the return statement, would it work any differently.

Someone please explain elaborately because i am just not getting it.

Comment: Hint: Use a debugger to step through `total.combine(trans1).combine(trans2).combine(trans3);`

Comment: Copy of this object will be written to stack, but will not be read, and will be discarded next moment

Comment: @Arkady - There will be no copy. Note the return type.

Comment: Tihs is done in order to enable chaining. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Comment: Oh, you're right)

Answer (score 6):

It is a common way to make the next construction work:

```
Sales_data x, y, z;
// some code here
auto res = x.combine(y).combine(z);
```

When you call:

```
x.combine(y)
```

`x` is changed and reference to `x` is returned, so you have an opportunity to call `combine()` on this changed instance via the reference returned on the prevous step once more time:

```
x.combine(y).combine(z);
```

---

Another popular example is `operator=()` implementation. So, if you implement `operator=` for a custom class it is often a good idea to return a reference to the instance:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&)
    {
        // impl
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Which makes an assignment work for your class as it works for standard types:

```
Foo x, y, z;
// some code here
x = y = z;
```

Answer (score 2):

One benefit of defining the function as you have defined with `return` statement is that it allows consecutive calls like the code below possible:

```
// assuming that trans1 and trans2 are defined and initialized properly earlier
total.combine(trans1).combine(trans2);
// now total contains values from trans1 and trans2
```

This is equivalent to:

```
// assuming that trans1 and trans2 are defined and initialized properly earlier
total.combine(trans1);
total.combine(trans2);
// now total contains values from trans1 and trans2
```

but it is a little more succinct and brief.

However, if you do not need or like to use the earlier version, you can declare the function to return `void`.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand it returns an instance of the object but it is not returning that instance to anything as we can see during function call

Correct, in this case.

But you *could* use the return value if you wanted to. It's there just in case.

This is a common convention, allowing for function call *chaining*.

> Also if i don't write the return statement, would it work any differently.

It would have undefined behaviour, because the function has a return type and therefore must return *something*. But you could make the return type `void` without altering the functionality of this particular program, sure.